# UWP - search the gridview regardless of uppercase or lowercase letters

Tags: c#, search, gridview, uwp

I have a gridview containing files from within a folder and adding a search function. I encountered a problem while searching, that is if the file name contained a large letter, but I typed it using lowercase letters, then it can't be found.
Like the picture below:

1. use lowercase
   [image: image 1]
2. Use uppercase
   [image: image 2]

How to overcome it, so as not to care about lowercase letters and uppercase letters in search results?

Code:

```
ObservableCollection<Book> datasource = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
private void SearchText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchText.Text))
                {
                    this.itemGridView.ItemsSource = this.datasource.Where((item) => { return item.Name.Contains(searchText.Text); });
                }
                else
                {
                    this.itemGridView.ItemsSource = datasource;
                }
            }
```

Book.cs:

```
public class Book
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Direktori { get; set; }

        public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `StringComparison` parameter to the `Contains()` method. So like this:

```
return item.Name.Contains(searchText.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```